# Uninstall module form command line odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

I tried to uninstall my custom module by using

```
'./odoo.py -d db_name --uninstall module_name(s)' command.
```

But I get the error:

> 'bash: ./odoo.py: No such file or directory'

How can I fix  it? How  can i  know a module is installed or not?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-uninstall-a-module-from-command-line-36076

Answer (score 1):

In odoo 12, I ran the below command in psql:

```
UPDATE ir_module_module SET state = 'to remove' WHERE name = 'app_library';
```

Once its updated, restart the odoo server:

```
python odoo-bin -d demodb (windows)
 ./odoo-bin -d demodb (linux)
```

The module installed before is completely uninstalled.

Comment: it's not working for the module still in "to Remove" state and it's not uninstalled

Answer (score 1):

Try executing this command:

```
UPDATE ir_module_module SET state = 'uninstalled' WHERE name = 'module_name';
```

in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any possible option now to uninstall the odoo module directly from the command prompt.

You can also see another option for help further for additional commands using

```
./odoo-bin --help
```

Which gives you the list of additional option with addons-path